# creating a trigger in transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I created simple table in Microsoft SQL Server and now I want to create "probably" easy trigger.

Here is my task:

When creating or modifying an employee, complete this column
email consisting of:

- the first two letters of the firstname,
- one dot,
- the first four letters of the surname and string '@gmail.com'.

Remember to remove any external whitespace and characters
to swap the inner spaces for the underscore.

This is my table which I'm using for trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE  employee
(
empID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
surname varchar(20),
firstname varchar(20),
age int,
email varchar(100)
)
```

I've tried to do it. Here is my version. Please check it and write what do you think about my solution:

```
create trigger create_email on employee
for insert,update
as
begin           
    declare @var_email varchar(100)
    set @var_email = substring((select firstname from inserted),1,2) + '.' + substring((select surname from inserted),1,4) + '@gmail.com'
    set @var_email = replace(@var_email,' ','_')
    update employee set email = @var_email where empID in (select empID from inserted)
end
```

end

Comment: You have a MAJOR flaw here. You are assuming there will only ever be a single row in the inserted table. You need to make this set based. You can use a join in an update statement which is what you need here.

Comment: Can you write it or give me some example? I am beginner and really don't know how to even correct it...

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This is obviously homework and I am not going to write this for you. How are you going to learn the subject if people online do your work for you? Try searching for using FROM in an UPDATE statement. It has been asked and answered around here dozens if not hundreds of times.

Comment: Ok boss . This was very helpful and motivating

Comment: Aside: Duplicate email addresses for multiple employees should provide plenty of entertainment. Perhaps a `rollback` would make sense if a duplicate would be created.

Comment: Where does your code "remember to remove the external whitespace", e.g. blanks, tabs, ...?

Comment: Since you are asking for opinions about your code, perhaps it is better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: @blaise Does the computed column approach work or is a trigger required?  I can add the trigger to my answer if you need it

Comment: @Aaron Dietz Trigger is required. Yes please you can add what you have done it will be very helpful.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for suggestion . After closing this topic I will use CodeReview. I thought I can ask everything on Stack Overflow . Sorry for beeing a problem :(

Comment: @blaise Added the trigger approach.  And your question is fine for SO, but it is missing is a true *question* (meaning with a question mark) hence the CodeReview suggestion.  If you ended on *Below is my code attempt, what am I doing wrong?*  then it would be perfect for SO.  I don't get the hate on helping with homework when someone has clearly tried, and most people here feel the same way.

Answer (score 2):

It would make more sense to use a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
empID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
surname varchar(20),
firstname varchar(20),
age int,
email as REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(firstname,2)+'.'+LEFT(surname,4)+'@gmail.com')),' ','_')
)
```

The trigger version would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER create_email ON employee
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE e
    SET e.email = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(i.firstname,2)+'.'+LEFT(i.surname,4)+'@gmail.com')),' ','_')
)
    FROM employee e
    JOIN inserted i on e.empID = i.empID
END
```